# Custom aggregation of Finance data in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-finance

I am currently working on a calculation to identify data trend on stock prices and is currently using google finance libraries for the same.

I would like to compute the following information in an automated way.

- Percent of days with positive returns during the last x days
- Standard deviation of the returns(price diff per day, not the actual stock price) for this period

I am currently placing the

`GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOGL","price",WORKDAY( TODAY(), -200 ) , TODAY(), "DAILY")`

in a separate sheet and calculating the differences per row by doing a lookup of the previous row and aggregating the data.

I have to update the ticker manually for every stock that I am interested in and then copy the summary information to master sheet.

Is there any automated way that I can compute this as single/configurable calculations ? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete all in range **C2:D** and paste this in **C2** then drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SUM(IFERROR(IF(
 QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4, "price", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -200), 
 TODAY(), "daily"), "select Col2 offset 2", 0)>
 QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4, "price", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -200), 
 TODAY(), "daily"), "select Col2 offset 1", 0), 1, 0)))/COUNTA(
 QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4, "price", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -200), 
 TODAY(), "daily"), "select Col2 offset 1", 0)), STDEV(IFERROR((
 QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4, "price", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -200), 
 TODAY(), "daily"), "select Col2 offset 2", 0)-
 QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4, "price", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -200), 
 TODAY(), "daily"), "select Col2 offset 1", 0))/
 QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4, "price", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -200), 
 TODAY(), "daily"), "select Col2 offset 1", 0)))})
```

[image: 0]